# How to retrieve ID from Firebase Database using AngularFire

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

My Firebase Database has structure as follows:

fire-demo-123

- course
  1 : "course1"
  2 : "course2"
  3 : "course3"
  -MzOn2s : "course4"

Currently I am fetching list using this code
**component.ts**

```
title = 'FirebaseDemo';
  // courses: any[];

  courses$;
  course$;
  author$;
  todos$: AngularFireList<any>;
  // subscription : Subscription;

  constructor(public db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    db.list('/course')
      .valueChanges()
      .subscribe((inp) => {
        this.courses$ = inp;
        console.log(this.courses$);
// Output is ["course1", "course2", "course3", "course4"]
          });
```

**component.html**

```
<h3>List</h3>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let course of courses$">{{course}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

But is there any way to get them with reference to id like `{id:1,value:"course1"}...`

Here's my database export.

```
{
  
  "course" : {
    "1" : "course1",
    "2" : "course2",
    "3" : "course3",
    "-MZOnCn1YdQ2sGLhajuL" : "course4"
  }
}
```

I am trying to get courses with id.

Comment: Can you please share a database export so we can clone the problem on our side? A small example JSON

Comment: I've posted an answer. Let me know if that's what you were looking for. You can accept the answer by clicking tick icon so that others know the issue is resolved else feel free to ask further questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping your database structure the same, best you can do is to loop over all the keys and create a new object as shown below:

```
const courses = {
    "1": "course1",
    "2": "course2",
    "3": "course3",
    "-MZOnCn1YdQ2sGLhajuL": "course4"
}

const res = []
Object.keys(courses).forEach((course) => {
    res.push({id: course, value: courses[course]})
})
console.log(res);
```

I tried running the code above and worked for me.
[image]

Please make sure you replace the `courses` object with the snapshot value from realtime database.

Comment: @KartikDolas please read the last line of my answer, replace it with the snapshot.

Comment: @KartikDolas also can you please use `db.object()` instead of `db.list()` ?

Comment: I am totally noob in Firebase. please refer my code in TS and let me know what is snapshot in my case. I am trying with db.object('course').snapshotChanges() and db.object('course'). Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The "inp" should be the snapshot.  Can you please use db.object() instead of .list() in your existing code and console.log(inp) and share that here?